# Strange behavior on .then and .catch

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have a script with a .then .catch. (below) but i don't understand why .catch is triggered.

Somebody could explain to me ?

```
passport.use(new BasicStrategy( (username, password, callback) => {
User.findOne({where: { username: username }})
  .then(function (data) {
    var verify = data.verifyPassword(password);
    if(verify == true) { console.log("VERIFY = " + verify); callback(null, data); } 
       }
  )
  .catch( err => {
    console.log('catch  '+ err);
    callback(null, false);
    }
  )
  }
  ));
```

**My console result:**

VERIFY = true
catch  Error: passport.initialize() middleware not in use

We are through .then AND catch again despite a "true" from verify and an "if" returning " true too.

Comment: what happens inside `callback()`?

Comment: Well, have you loaded the `passport.initialize()` middleware before this?

Comment: My guess is that the `callback` function triggers an error. To test this, try removing the call to `callback` and see if that changes things. Then show us what `callback` contains and we might be able to help further.

Comment: You right @Samathingamajig. Thanks !